# Everything froze after Idling

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I have only been using Linux for about 1-2 months and still learning and so...

**PROBLEM:**

I am using Kubuntu 20.04... I sometimes leave my laptop open and do some stuff at home like cooking and such, after that I come back like **4-5 mins** everything is frozen, Latte is gone, keyboard input isnt working, my open tabs like firefox is still there but I couldnt interact with it. The only thing I can do is move my mouse around but not interact with anything.

*What seems to be the problem?*

I dont know if these informations will help but here're some infos 'bout my system:

- Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.8
- Kernel Version: 5.13.0-30-generic
- Processors: 4xIntel Pentium Silver N6000 @1.10 GHz
- Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM

Comment: That might be because your computer is lacking CPU processing power. On my computer using the i5 CPU, the computer randomly freezes during my online lesson. The CPU you have is Pentium, it's an old CPU afaik, so that might be your CPU's fault, not any software's.

Comment: @Emoji A Pentium Silver N6000 is the *new* entry level Intel CPU: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/212330/intel-pentium-silver-n6000-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-30-ghz.html . It should be more than enough for a LOT of work.

Comment: @Emoji, ah so the possible problem is the CPU processing power huh? I wonder if autocpu-freq is messing with my cpu... like I havent configured autocpu-freq properly so its screwing my system up making everything crash when idle...